# NLTK: conllstr2tree does not work properly (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

The example which illustrates what I'm trying to do is at part 3.1 of http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Here is essentially what it is :

```
import nltk
text = " ..... "  #Whatever the text should be
nltk.chunk.conllstr2tree(text, chunk_types=['NP']).draw()
```

This generates the tree based on the `text` given.

The code I have written seeks to use the input from a text file.
So after opening it, I use `readlines` to get a String version of it.

```
import nltk, re, pprint
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
f1 = f.read().strip()
f2 = ' '.join(f1.split())
nltk.chunk.conllstr2tree(f2, chunk_types=['NP']).draw()
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-768af8cd2f77> in <module>()
      3 f1 = f.read().strip()
      4 f2 = ' '.join(f1.split())
----> 5 nltk.chunk.conllstr2tree(f2, chunk_types=['NP']).draw()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/util.py in conllstr2tree(s, chunk_types, root_label)
    380         match = _LINE_RE.match(line)
    381         if match is None:
--> 382             raise ValueError('Error on line %d' % lineno)
    383         (word, tag, state, chunk_type) = match.groups()
    384 

ValueError: Error on line 0
```

Comment: What _are_ you trying to do? Chunk NPs? Identify named entities? Something else entirely? It's not at all clear from your snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in raw string data from **sample.txt**, trimming whitespace  `f1`, and then tokenizing on spaces `f2`.

If you look at [the example from the NTLK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#developing-and-evaluating-chunkers) where they mention the chunking method,

```
nltk.chunk.conllstr2tree(text, chunk_types=['NP']).draw()
```

the `text` variable is a sequence of IOB tagged data like so:

```
text = """
   he PRP B-NP
   accepted VBD B-VP
   the DT B-NP
   position NN I-NP
   of IN B-PP
   vice NN B-NP
   chairman NN I-NP
   of IN B-PP
   Carlyle NNP B-NP
   Group NNP I-NP
   , , O
   a DT B-NP
   merchant NN I-NP
   banking NN I-NP
   concern NN I-NP
   . . O
"""
```

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/412263afdba4ec6c799bf5e138090d871cbcee15/nltk/chunk/util.py) documentation the conllstr2tree method:

> Return a chunk structure for a single sentence
>       encoded in the given CONLL 2000 style string.
>       This function converts a CoNLL IOB string into a tree.
>       It uses the specified chunk types
>       (defaults to NP, PP and VP), and creates a tree rooted at a node
>       labeled S (by default).

The problem is that you are simple not passing in the correct format (CoNLL 2000 Wall Street Journal), which should look like so (without the slashes):

```
token / POS Tag / IOB-Chunk Type
```

So you will need a couple of extra steps:

1. Find the likely Part-of-Speech Tag for each word.
2. Find the chunk type
3. Prepend the appropriate IOB tag.

It would be unreasonable (for an SO question) to provide an example code snippet as this is quite a lot of work, but hopefully this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Good explanation. And the NLTK book chapter cited by the OP gives complete code for writing and training a chunker; one just has to read through the chapter and get the relevant parts.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, good point. Thanks for pointing that out! He should be rocking in no time.